# What is the deffinition of convexity defect in image processing?

Tags: image-processing

I am seeing this term in every image processing object recognition tutorial, but no one explains what this is. They only explain how to find convexity defects but what is a convexity defect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple words, convexity defect is a cavity in an object (blob, contour) segmented out from an image. That means an area that do not belong to the object but located inside of its outer boundary -convex hull (read documentation of cv::convexHull function for details).

The image below shows it better than million of words. Areas between fingers (all marked with arrows) in this schematics of a hand contour are the convexity defects.

[image: Convexity defects example]

You can find the defects using OpenCV's function [`cv::convexityDefects`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull#convexitydefects).